# Flutter: flow_builder: skipping the route to access next one

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, gorouter

Is it possible in Flutter, using GoRouter and FlowBuilder, once I have my route with have 3 different pages (pageOne, pageTwo, pageThree), where we open initially pageOne, and using `context.flow<T>().update`, we navigate through them. To navigate to particular page we have to complete condition (which we manage by `context.flow<T>.update`).

Accessing to that route from different part of my application (being in another route) is possible, but initially opens pageOne. Is it possible to access pageTwo and skip the pageOne once I have a correct parameter to complete condition accessing to pageTwo?